# upgrade code ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have value in my controller

```
@tour = Tour.find(:first, 
:conditions => ["beginDate in (?) AND tour LIKE ? AND duration + 1 = ? OR
                 beginDate in (?) AND tour LIKE ? AND duration + 1 = ?",
                 @day.day,  @day.travel.tour.name, @day.cruise.tour_days_count,
                 @day.day, 'Some Name', @day.cruise.tour_days_count])
```

He works fine. How can I upgrade this code, create him more compact? 
ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@tour = Tour.where("beginDate in (?) AND tour IN (?) AND (duration + 1) = ?", 
                    @day.day,  [@day.travel.tour.name, 'Some Name'], @day.cruise.tour_days_count])
       .first
```

Comment: `where` need rails >= 3.0.0, and he rails 2.3!

Answer (score 0):

```
@tour = Tour.find(:first, :conditions => ["beginDate in (?) AND tour IN (?) AND (duration + 1) = ?", 
  @day.day, [@day.travel.tour.name, 'Some Name'], @day.cruise.tour_days_count])
```